# Windows Explorer (Context Menu)

Tags: powershell, explorer

This is a two part questions for Windows Explorer (context menu).

First, I have this code in VBScript that gives back to me in a string of all the selected files in an instance of Windows Explorer. I plan to convert this VBScript code to PowerShell. Is there a better way of doing this in PowerShell?  Otherwise, I will convert it and use the same COMObject "Shell.Application".

```
Private Function GetSelectedFiles() 'Returns paths as array of strings
    Dim strData
    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    With oShell
        Dim oWindow
        For Each oWindow In .Windows
            Dim oSelectedItem
            For Each oSelectedItem In oWindow.Document.SelectedItems
                strData = strData & oSelectedItem.Path & vbCRLF
            Next
             
            Exit For        'Exit after the first looping so that it does not pickup the other Windows Explorer instances.
       Next
    End With
    Set oShell = Nothing

    If Right(strData, Len(vbCRLF)) = vbCRLF Then strData = Left(strData, Len(strData) - Len(vbCRLF))
 
    GetSelectedFiles = strData
End Function
```

Second, with the above code, I can save it into a script and bind the script to a registry entry "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell". This will allow me to right-click on a folder and select on the entry to get the selected files.  However, I would like to do it similar to WinRar where I can right-click on any selected files/folders and run the script to get the selected files/folders.

Notice, this is not the same as "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell" since it will run multiple instances of the same script.  For example, if I select multiple text files and right-click select Notepad, it would open multiple instances of Notepad for each text file.  This is not what I am looking for.

I am looking for similar to WinRar, PowerISO, etc..., it would run only one instance but captured all selected files and feed it to the script or program.

Do I have to build the object in C# or something?  Or is there another way of doing this without building an object in C#?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my second question by adding the shortcut of the script to SendTo folder which is located at:

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

I also found this tool but I rather use the above because I don't like to install additional stuffs if I can avoid it.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/add-customize-send-to-menu-windows

Comment: For my first question, I am not able to get the selected files when I convert my VBScript.  Can anyone help look over this? `Clear-Host
$ShellApplicationCOM = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$SelectedItems = $ShellApplicationCOM.Windows(0).Document.SelectedItems

#$SelectedItems.Count
#$SelectedItems

ForEach ($Item in $SelectedItems)
{
 Write-Host $Item.Path
}`

Comment: In **PowerShell**, com objects that represent collections have to be wrapped in an array operator before the items in the collection can be referencec by dot-sourcing or enumerated in a ForEach loop. Try: `@(@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows())[0].DOcument.SelectedItems()).Path`

Comment: @Keith, I spent over 10 hours trying to figure this out since recently I have been learning PowerShell and converting all of my VBScripts.  **I have no idea what you are talking about but it worked sir!**  I would like to understand more on this wrapping concept.  What keywords should I be goggling, especially what the @ signs wrapping mean?  I believe @ is short hand for looping right? I thought I was going out of my mind because my VBScript worked fine but could not get the PowerShell to work. Greatly thank you for your input and an end to this long research.

Comment: What is dot-sourcing that you have mentioned? And your code was not in a ForEach loop is it because the @ signs did the same thing?

Comment: I misspoke in my earlier comment when I referenced "dot sourcing". The `.` character serves multiple functions in **PowerShell**, and what I was referring to is using `.` as the [`Member-access operator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#member-access-operator-) on a list/collection  to perform [`Member-access enumeration`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2), which returns a collection of property values.

Comment: `@()` is the [`array subexpression operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--). It creates an array from whatever object(s) are within the parentheses. So,  `Widnow.Document.SelectedItems()` returns a *single* [`FolderItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitems) com object -- which does not have a `Path` property. But wrapping with the array operator returns a collection of FolderItem objects, each with its own path...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I will look into them Keith.

**Unfortunately**, is it possible to grab the selected items of the TOPMOST window only, not Window(0)?  My VBscript was able to do this.  I mistakenly used the zero index and it keeps returning the first Window Explorer.

Comment: You can reference the last item in an array by using an index of `[-1]`. Try that...

Comment: That grabs the last item in the array, like you said Keith.  Unfortunately, not the active window. It is strange that the ForEach works differently between VBScript and PowerShell.  I believe in VBScript, it grabs the active window.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. I know there's an API you can Pinvoke to get the active window. That would be the most robust. If you're unlikely to have multiple **Explorer** windows open to the same folder, you might be able to test the parent path of your selected items against the paths of open **Explorer** windows...

Comment: Keith, I was able to use the api FindWindow to find the TopMost Windows Explorer and then use the  `| Where-Object {$_.Hwnd -EQ $hwndTopMostFileExplorer}` on your code. It worked.  Thanks for your dedication to this thread Keith.

Comment: You're welcome. You should edit your answer to include your final resolution and associated code for the sake of posterity.